# Sorting email address according to occurrences of each domain

Tags: python, sorting, regex, email

My code:

```
import re
mbox = open('mailbox.txt')
ndict = {}
for line in mbox:
    domain = re.findall('From [^ ].*@([^ ]*)', line)
    if domain:
        if domain[0] in ndict:
            ndict[domain[0]] += 1
        else:
            ndict[domain[0]] = 1

print_list = [print(i) for i in sorted([(i, ndict[i]) for i in 
          list(ndict.keys())], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
```

I don't like how I create a dictionary and then immediately convert it into a list (which I'm doing in order to sort it), as it seems un-Pythonic to me. Is there a more Pythonic way to do this without using dictionaries?

i.e. Can you do this by making a list and appending tuples of the domains and number of occurrences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I suggest you get a linter such as Prospector or flake8, this can tell if your code is un-Pythonic. Some people prefer hinters like black.

   Your code doesn't conform to PEP 8 which is *the standard* when it comes to Python. Your comprehension is hard to read because it doesn't conform to best practices.
2. I'd recommend moving your code into a `main` function and use an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. This reduces global pollution and prevents your code from running accidentally.
3. When you see something like:

   ```
   if key in my_dict:
       my_dict[key] += value
   else:
       my_dict[key] = default + value
   ```

   Then you should probably use `dict.get` which can get the following code:

   ```
   my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, default) + value
   ```

   In this case you can add more sugar by using `collections.defaultdict`, as it will default missing keys to 0.

   ```
   import collections

   my_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
   my_dict[key] += 1
   ```
4. Don't use comprehensions with side effects, they're hard to understand and are better expressed as standard `for` loops. This is as the list you're making is absolutely pointless.
5. You can use `dict.items()` rather than your comprehension with `dict.keys()`.

```
import re
import collections


def main():
    with open('mailbox.txt') as mbox:
        ndict = collections.defaultdict(int)
        for line in mbox:
            domain = re.findall('From [^ ].*@([^ ]*)', line)
            if domain:
                ndict[domain[0]] += 1

        for item in sorted(ndict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
            print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can replace the majority of your code with `collections.Counter`.

```
import re
import collections


def main():
    with open('mailbox.txt') as mbox:
        counts = collections.Counter(
            domain[0]
            for domain in re.findall('From [^ ].*@([^ ]*)', line)
            if domain
        )
        for item in counts.most_common():
            print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for telling me about PEP 8 (I didn't even know about it before lol; apologies!) and all these new methods and libraries! `dict.get` I feel would be an especially useful one for me. However, I have to ask why you would use `dict.items` over `dict.keys` in that instance. Also I think you might have made a mistake in your last code block, you wrote count instead of counts when iterating. Thank you for your time btw!

Comment: @rivershen No problem, we all have to start somewhere :) I'm unsure what you mean by your `dict.items` question, but I'll give it a stab anyway. Since `[(i, ndict[i]) for i in ndict.keys()]` is pretty much the same as `ndict.items()` then there are no benefits to using the former - it's longer to type and to read. Yes I did make a mistake, I have fixed that now thank you.